# VB Outlook Addin to transfer email information

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am attempting to create an add-in for outlook for where i work. The department in question use an in house built database application with a microsoft access front end built in vba.

Currently the team copy and paste information into the system. I have been tasked with creating an addin that will copy the necessary information such as

- email address the email was sent from
- Date & Time it was sent

  - message body

I have created the ribbon and have a button in place that currently displays "hello World".

Could anyone tell me how to get VB to read the information from the message? I have done some research on the internet but cannot find much information on this particular topic.

Comment: Is the ribbon button on an Outlook Explorer or Inspector?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start here. This talks about how to do a lot of things with outlook using interop, which is the way you will need to work with it from a .Net addin.

[How Do I... Outlook PIA Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb612741.aspx)